# Panel data regression

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-3, regression, panel

I have GIS data on individual events (with timestamps), and I am running a panel data regression, with the outcome variable being the number of events by district by month. My independent variables also include individual coordinates in each district.

I wonder if the right way to go forward is to merge the different layers in QGIS (district shapefiles, event data etc) and export the resulting attribute table as CSV so that I can run the regression in R. If yes, I am struggling a bit with what exactly to do. Is there a way in which I can export the data directly as a panel, which includes the number of events for each district each month? Or am I on completely the wrong track?

Comment: What's a "district-month"? Google results for that term include school district monthly calendars and an "Arts District Month," but neither seems relevant here. Please [edit] the definition into your question.